# How can I use Python Threading with parameter passing between threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, udp

**1.
Summarize the problem**
I am working with Python 2 and a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian Buster. Trying to limit the speed at which my program reads sensor data from my Android device that is using Sockets to send its data via UDP connection. IE: I built this as a small laser trip wire app and to start I wanted to increment a count accumulator every time the sensor value dropped below a certain number, indicating a tripped laser. However, the data reads in so fast that count is incremented many times for each time the sensor level drops below. How can I only read the UDP data every X seconds?

**2.
Describe what you’ve tried**

- I have tried time.sleep() but from what I have read, this is a blocking function and after testing, it does indeed stop my program being able to update the sensor data over the UDP socket
- I have tried Threading but I cannot figure out how to pass in the sensor data from one thread into another.
- I researched join() but the technical documentation I happened across wasn't very beginner friendly.
- Some posts here recomend setting up a client/server interface, but I am not sure how to do that either.

**3.
When appropriate, show some code**
Here is my current progress for a threaded solution. I am using the android app called SensorUDP and with the Ambient Light sensor on and Send Data activated this program will read in the UDP data and print it. even without the UDP data it will still run the count thread.

```
import socket
from struct import *
import time
import threading

#We have 0-92 over a 1024 byte buffer representing distinct
#sensors being sent over UDP from my android smartphone
#this test program im only pulling byte 56 for Ambient Light sensing
#a laser shining into my phones sensor has 30,000-50,000 lums so anything
#less then that range must mean the laser was tripped


#UDP = SOCK_DGRAM, AF_INET = Internet
UDP_IP = "192.168.1.149" #my rpi4 address
print "Receiver IP: ", UDP_IP
UDP_PORT = 5000 #arbitrary for now but needs to match my androids broadcast
print "Port: ", UDP_PORT
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                    socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT)) #complete the binding

running = True
count = 0
laserOn = 1000 #using a low lums to test so I dont have to use laser every time
aLight = 0
result_available = threading.Event() #.set() this when the data is recieved
threadTimer = 5

def calcAmbLight():

# Continuously read from the UDP socket
   
    while running:
       
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
        #the data from the app Im using to push the sensor data needs to
        #be unpacked
        aLight = "%.1f" %unpack_from ('!f', data, 56)
        print ("Ambient Light = ", aLight)

def displayCount():
    count = 0
    while running:
        time.sleep(1)
        #how to pass aLight into this thread from the other thread?
        if aLight < laserOn:
            count = count + 1

        print("Current aLight: ",aLight)
        print("Current Count: ", count)
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
              
    #create a basicthread to run calcAmbLight
    calcAmb = threading.Thread(target= calcAmbLight)
    calcAmb.start()
   
    dispCount = threading.Thread(target = displayCount)
    dispCount.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the current setup is due to the fact that you are not declaring `aLight` as global in `calcAmbLight()`. Declaring it as a global variable should allow this to work.

```py
def calcAmbLight():
    global aLight  # Set the global aLight, instead of a local stack variable

    while running:

        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
        #the data from the app Im using to push the sensor data needs to
        #be unpacked
        aLight = "%.1f" %unpack_from ('!f', data, 56)
        print ("Ambient Light = ", aLight)
```

Comment: he says that he is getting a signal change when its tripped.... the other loop just keeps incrementing the counter too many times ...

Comment: If they are using the code posted, the other thread will not be picking up the changes. The global variable ```aLight``` is never modified, only a variable local to ```calcAmbLight``` is changed. The question specifically asks how to pass a variable between threads.

Comment: Thank you Robert for the idea to use global variable declaration however it does not seem to be working unless I am doing something wrong once again. 

After declaring the variables Im using between the two threads as global, attempts to run the program will say "NameError: global name 'x' is not defined" for any 'x' that is declared a global variable and is not in the same thread as the declaration
ie: declaring global aLight variable in calcAmbLight() def and then trying to use aLight in displayCount() causes this error. Declaring aLight as global aLight in global space doesnt work either

Comment: Please ignore last comment, as I misunderstood, apparently I must keep the declaration of aLight in global space and then when referencing aLight in a function  I must declare global aLight within the function to let the function know I am talking about the aLight that was declared in global space. Thank you!